# I got Potential Problems in Bigbluebutton installation

Tags: nginx, bigbluebutton

I Got some Potential Problems when I Install Bigbluebutton in my Ubuntu
   as well as I got Nginx not running.
   I Don't Know how to clear, Anyone Plzzzz?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Check your ip address using command ifconfig
2. Then run this command sudo bbb-conf --setip 192.168.0.211(replace it with you ip)
3. Then edit the file using command "sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/bigbluebutton" 
   add the ip address from step 1 in this file
4. Now run this "sudo bbb-conf" it will restart bigbluebutton server and clear the log files

Following steps 1 to 4 should resolve the issue